# Java enum constructor is called multiple times

Tags: java, enums

I see enum usage like below.

```
public enum MyEnum {
  ENUM1(1),
  ENUM2(2),
  ENUM3(3);

  private int enumValue;
  MyEnum(int i) { this.enumValue = i; }
  public int getEnum() { return this.enumValue; }
}

// this is the call
MyEnum.ENUM1.getEnum()
```

When above call is made, constructor of the MyEnum is called three times. All I want to take is a value but three instances are created! Isn't this a bad thing or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** What I understand is that when the second call is made `MyEnum.ENUM3.getEnum()`, no more new instance is created.

Comment: Well, `ENUM1`, `ENUM2`, and `ENUM3` all have to be constructed, don't they?

Comment: learn what `.ordinal()` is

Comment: You have defined three instances, so it must create the instances you defined.  If you want less instances, define the number you want.

Comment: Can you explain why `this a bad thing`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ooops so sorry. I thought these instances are created for each call.

Comment: @RicardoCristianRamirez Once per class load.  Different class loaders could load it once each, but this is relatively rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three enum constants

```
ENUM1(1),
ENUM2(2),
ENUM3(3);
```

For each constant, the constructor needs to be invoked. This is normal behavior.

The constants are all initialized when the enum class is loaded and initialized.

Comment: Three instances are created on the heap and then they are destroyed. Doing something like this causes perfomance loss. So why people prefer something like this?

Comment: @RicardoCristianRamirez They are not destroyed. They are referenced by `static` variables (hidden to the programmer) in the `enum` class. They cannot be GC'ed (until the class is GC'ed).

Answer (score 1):

The three instancee ENUM1, ENUM2 and ENUM3 are created - due to your declaraton of MyEnum when the class is loaded. Your call simply retrieves the int associated with ENUM1.

This is the way Java's enum is defined. You can't change it.